# Usando combobox dinâmico como enviar o id para servidor automaticamente sem usar o botão submit e retornar todos valores onde id é igual?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou usando um datalist dinâmico que faz auto-complete.

No combobox abaixo esta ligada com base de dados `gestao_vendas`, onde na tabela estoque ele traz todos os nomes dos produtos e o respectivo `idProduto`.

Como fazer para quando eu clicar numa opção do combobox ele deve enviar o `idProduto` para servidor e logo de seguida retornar a linha onde o `idProduto` é igual, automaticamente sem precisar de clicar no Botão?

```
<input type="text" id="txtID" name="Produtos" list="ent" />
<datalist id="ent">
<label>select a Produtos from list:</label>
<select name="Produtos">

<?php 
  include 'teste/conexao/conexao.php';

  $selecionar="SELECT * FROM `gestao_vendas`.`estoque`";
  try {
  $resultado = $conexao->prepare($selecionar);
  $resultado->execute();
  if(count($resultado)){
  foreach ($resultado as $res) {    
?>
  <option id="<?php echo $res['codProduto'];?>" value="<?php echo $res['NomeProduto'];?>"> </option>

<?php
  }
  }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    //  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
?>

</select>
</datalist>
```

Eu gostaria que visualiza-se nesta tabela.

```
<?php

$selecionar="SELECT * FROM `estoque` WHERE `codProduto`=$idProduto";
  try {
  $resultado = $conexao->prepare($selecionar);
  $resultado->execute();
  while ($mostrar = $resultado->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {                
  ?>

<tr>
  <td><?php echo $mostrar->codProduto; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $mostrar->NomeProduto; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $mostrar->descricao; ?></td>
</tr>   

<?php
  }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
  //  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

não sei se entendi muito bem, mas precisará utilizar ajax para que seja enviado uma requisição dinamicamente sem precisar clicar no botão. Precisará também gerar a tabela com javascript.

Código para pegar o id do option selecionado:
https://jsfiddle.net/4ar90ztx/1/

Para o ajax teste este trecho de código:

```
$('#id_do_select').change(function () {
            var codProduto = $('#id_do_select').find(":selected").attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "pagina.php",
                data: { codProduto: codProduto},
                method: "POST",
                success: function(){
                   //Lógica para gerar a tabela dinâmicamente;
                }
            });
    });
```

Para pegar o valor do código do produto no php:

```
if(isset($_POST['codProduto'])){
   $codProduto = $_POST['codProduto'];
}
```